# replicate Task Manager into powershell output

Tags: windows, powershell, process, task-manager

I am new in windows powershell. I want to replicate task manager Process GUI information into excel continuously for every 5 min. Can it be possible ?

Comment: You are probably looking for [Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-6).

Comment: But how can automate its execution for every 5 min and append that ourput into csv

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `Get-Process` cmdlet and Task Scheduler.

try the following:

```
Get-Process | Select Handles,NPM,PM,WS,CPU,Id,SI,ProcessName,@{Name = 'Timestamp'; Expression = ({(Get-Date)})} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Junk\Processes.csv -Append
```

If you save this into a .ps1 file, you can then call it with a scheduled task and repeat the task every 5 minutes:
[image]

Alternatively - you can use a PowerShell Loop and leave the script running in a window for as long as you need it to:

```
do {
    Get-Process | Select Handles,NPM,PM,WS,CPU,Id,SI,ProcessName,@{Name = 'Timestamp'; Expression = ({(Get-Date)})} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Junk\Processes.csv -Append
    start-sleep -Seconds 300
} while ($true -eq $true)
```

(in this case - 300 seconds is 5 minutes!)

Comment: Thank you for this help.. But if I change Powershell execution policy to *remoteassigned* and then I wish to stop this powershell then how can I do that. 

I am assuming that it cold be stopped from processes in task manager. But don't know yet.

Comment: if you change your execution policy to RemoteSigned (not assigned) - it will make no difference at all.  You can still kill the PowerShell.exe process from task manager, stop the windows scheduled job execution, use taskkill.exe to kill the process or stop it in any other way you find suitable.